# Xamarin Android Support lib references broken since installing Google Play Services

Tags: android, xamarin

I have a project that I attempted to install Google Player Services through NuGet. Since trying to install the google package, my android support libraries as well as the google play service libraries are all showing up in my references as broken, no matter how I try to add, reinstall or change the references. They always break, throwing `The "ResolveLibraryProjectImports" task failed unexpectedly.` as an error in response.

I have looked around and tried everything that sounded remotely like my issue, to no avail. Any help would be appreciated.

I am running Xamarin v4.3.0.789 (4d2ed3d) with Xamarin.Android v7.1.0.43 (4a52f1e)

Comment: Update your `Xamarin.Build.Download` package to the latest release.

Comment: Did as you said, no success, after further investigation, it looks like there is some conflictions in NuGet Packages, I am currently trying to figure what they are

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure why this fixed the issue. However after looking through, I realised that version of my packages had been updated, I assume that Google Player Services forced that, which then caused my whole project to go haywire.

Installed the version of packages I was using beforehand and it works again.